# R: conditional populating of a column in a table based on input from other columns

Tags: r

I have a table with dates in column 1 (Column titled "Date") and values in columns 2 through 5 (Columns titled "A"->"D").

---

```
Date   A  B  C  D
1/1/16 12 75 38 88
1/2/16 32 76 44 34
```

etc.

---

I need to create additional 6th column E that contains the following:

For each row:

If value in column A > B > C then value in column E = X

If value in column A < B < C then value in column E = Y

for anything else value in column E = Z

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why would you provide example data that satisfies neither of the conditions you particularly want tested?

Comment: sorry, i just wanted to give an example of the table format, actual values do not follow the rules i mentioned. thanks for catching this!

Answer (score 1):

```
# Here I'm simulating your original dataset     
df <- data.frame(Date=seq(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date()+9,by=1), A = seq(1,20,2),
                 B = rep(10,1,1), C=abs(rnorm(10)), D = rnorm(10))  
# Create E
df$E <- NA  
df$E[df$A > df$B & df$B > df$C] <- "X"
df$E[df$A < df$B & df$B < df$C] <- "Y"
df$E[is.na(df$E)]               <- "Z"
df



         Date  A  B            C              D E
1  2016-06-29  1 10 0.5833273005 -0.25244803522 Z
2  2016-06-30  3 10 0.4291374487  0.01669504752 Z
3  2016-07-01  5 10 1.7079045597  1.28413741595 Z
4  2016-07-02  7 10 0.2286708311  1.16421926818 Z
5  2016-07-03  9 10 0.6216853471  1.08934300378 Z
6  2016-07-04 11 10 1.4662821456 -0.58322427720 X
7  2016-07-05 13 10 0.8255102263  0.65217873906 X
8  2016-07-06 15 10 1.6185672627  0.04195996408 X
9  2016-07-07 17 10 0.6752993011 -2.31746231694 X
10 2016-07-08 19 10 0.2901133125  0.97969860678 X

# Create E only for a subset of rows, like 6:10 
df$E <- NA
df$E[1:5] <- "nothing applied to this row"  
df$E[df$A > df$B & df$B > df$C & 6:10] <- "X"
df$E[df$A < df$B & df$B < df$C & 6:10] <- "Y"
df$E[is.na(df$E) & 6:10]               <- "Z"
df

         Date  A  B            C              D                           E
1  2016-06-29  1 10 0.5833273005 -0.25244803522 nothing applied to this row
2  2016-06-30  3 10 0.4291374487  0.01669504752 nothing applied to this row
3  2016-07-01  5 10 1.7079045597  1.28413741595 nothing applied to this row
4  2016-07-02  7 10 0.2286708311  1.16421926818 nothing applied to this row
5  2016-07-03  9 10 0.6216853471  1.08934300378 nothing applied to this row
6  2016-07-04 11 10 1.4662821456 -0.58322427720                           X
7  2016-07-05 13 10 0.8255102263  0.65217873906                           X
8  2016-07-06 15 10 1.6185672627  0.04195996408                           X
9  2016-07-07 17 10 0.6752993011 -2.31746231694                           X
10 2016-07-08 19 10 0.2901133125  0.97969860678                           X
```

Comment: Thank you! I implemented this and it worked great! How would i go about reducing number of rows i would like to look at, lets say i want to do this only on rows 6 through 10. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3481603 see my updated explanation, but using Hack-R's example, you could do something like `df$E[df$A > df$B & df$B > df$C & seq_along(df$C) >= 6)] `

Comment: @user3481603 after pasting a bit from the Hack-R's answer above, the second subset has B > C, when I think you wanted C > B.  Just in case you happened to copy paste this into some medical device code :)

Comment: @user3481603 You just add the rows you want as a condition like this `df$E[df$A > df$B & df$B > df$C & 6:10]`

Comment: @dcc310 I was just showing the method. I'll update it.

Comment: @Hack-R will the 6:10 part work?  That vector would be 4 elements when the result of the inequality will be 10.  I believe the 6:10 will just be 'recycled' until it's of length 10, which probably isn't what OP wants.

Comment: @dcc310 I didn't really get all that, but you made me nervous enough to run a check and it seems to work fine. Asides from the example above I did this to verify `df$E <- 1:10; df$E[1:5];df$E[6:10]`. Just normal row indexing.

Comment: Question folks, what was your primary way of learning R? Was it through courses / work / school or just learning on your own?

Comment: regarding specific rows to be analyzed - i just ended up reducing my original table to the specific rows im interested in and then just analyzing all of them.

Comment: @Hack-R, sorry for the mixup. you're right that you can use that to index, but I believe the issue arises when combined with other logic vectors.  Consider for example: `myframe <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=11:15)` followed by `nrow(myframe[myframe$a < myframe$b & 1:3, ])`.  This outputs 5 rows, when `1:3` was probably aiming for 3 rows.  `rep(1, 5) + 1:3` gives `2 3 4 2 3` because the 1 and 2 get reused to make the vector lengths match.  For that snippet, I get a warning "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length", but used by itself for indexing is fine...

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work fine:

```
set.seed(1)
myframe = data.frame(date=1:10, a=sample(1:10), b=sample(1:10),     c=sample(1:10), d=sample(1:10), e=NA)
myframe[myframe$a > myframe$b & myframe$b > myframe$c, "e"] = "x"
myframe[myframe$a < myframe$b & myframe$b < myframe$c, "e"] = "y"
myframe[is.na(myframe$e), "e"] = "z"
myframe
```

Gives

```
   date  a  b  c  d e
1     1  3  3 10  5 z
2     2  4  2  2  6 z
3     3  5  6  6  4 z
4     4  7 10  1  2 z
5     5  2  5  9 10 y
6     6  8  7  8  8 z
7     7  9  8  7  9 x
8     8  6  4  5  1 z
9     9 10  1  3  7 z
10   10  1  9  4  3 z
```

if `x <- 1:4` gives `1 2 3 4` then `x < - 1:4 < 3` is `TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE`.  So, `someFrame[x, "someCol"]` selects that col from rows where x is TRUE, i.e. the first and second rows.  The same works for vectors, so `c("a", "b", "c", "d")[x]` returns `a b`.  I've heard this called "logical indexing", for what it's worth.

Comment: Also, what would be the easy way to reduce number of rows in the table, lets say i wanted to lopk at rows 6 thorugh 10 only.

Comment: @user3481603, see my comment to Hack-R's answer for how to limit to 6 and above.  The set.seed function is to make examples involving randomness reproducible for others, otherwise you would get a different "random" result every time.

Comment: @dcc310 - I don't get the same `myframe` with `set.seed(1)` as you do. Are you sure you ran it?